# I have four categories,but i want to display in sidebar only two categories which contains subcategories

Tags: magento-1.9

I have four categories in my site,but i need to display only two categories which contains subcategories in sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create local.xml file or edit below code on it for add side block

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="block-name" template="sideblock/categories.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="block-name" template="sideblock/categories.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

**Step 2:** Create **categories.phtml** /app/design/frontend//default/template/sideblock/categories.phtml

```
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); ?>
<?php if($currentCategory): ?>
    <?php $categories = Mage::registry('current_category')->getChildren(); ?>
    <?php $catArray = explode(',', $categories);?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Categories'); ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($catArray as $child): ?>
        <?php $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child ); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_child->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_child->getName(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 3: Open category page which have subcategory. You can see like this block. Please check attached image.

[image]